# How to nest queries using Spring Data JPA?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, criteria

How would I translate the following SQL into Criteria?

```
SELECT DISTINCT <column name> FROM <table>
WHERE <some other column> IN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT <column name 2> FROM <table 2> 
    WHERE <some other column 2> IN
        (SELECT <column name 3> FROM <table 3>
        WHERE <some other column 3> IN
            (SELECT <column name 4> from <table 4>
            WHERE <some other column 4> IN (0,1,2,3,4))))
```

Here are the Column value types I'll be searching on:

```
Column           Value Type
<column name>    String
<column name 2>  String
<column name 3>  Long
<column name 4>  Long
```

Answer (score 1):

SQL to translate:

```
SELECT DISTNCT <column name> FROM <table>
WHERE <some other column> IN 
    (SELECT DISTINT <column name 2> FROM <table 2> 
    WHERE <some other column 2> IN
        (SELECT <column name 3> FROM <table 3>
        WHERE <some other column 3> IN
            (SELECT <column name 4> from <table 4>
            WHERE <some other column 4> IN (0,1,2,3,4))))

Column           Value Type
<column name>    String
<column name 2>  String
<column name 3>  Long
<column name 4>  Long
```

SQL Translated into JPA Criteria:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = emf.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<String> cqTable = cb.createQuery(String.class);
Root<table> fromTable = cqTable .from(<table>.class);

Subquery<String> cqTable2 = cqTable.subquery(String.class);
Root<table 2> fromTable2 = cqTable2.from(<table 2>.class);

Subquery<Long> cqTable3 = cqTable2.subquery(Long.class);
Root<table 3> fromTable3 = cqTable3.from(<table 3>.class);

Subquery<Long> cqTable4 = cqTable3.subquery(Long.class);
Root<table 4> fromTable4 = cqTable4.from(<table 4>.class);

    cqTable4 = cqTable4.select(fromTable4.get("column 4").as(Long.class))
.where(fromTable4.get("some other column 4").in(new ArrayList<String>(){{
                                add("0");
                                add("1");
                                add("2");
                                add("3");
                                add("4");}}));

cqTable3 = cqTable3.select(fromTable3.get("column name 3").as(Long.class))
                .where(fromTable3.get("some other column 3")
                        .in(cqTable4));

cqTable2 = cqTable2.select(fromTable2.get("column name 2").as(String.class))
                .distinct(true).where(fromTable2.get("some other column 2")
                        .in(cqTable3));

cqTable = cqTable.select(fromTable.get("column name").as(String.class))
.distinct(true).where(fromTable.get("some other column").in(cqTable2)));

List<String results = emf.createEntityManager().createQuery(cqTable ).getResultList();
```

I hope this is able to help someone who is struggling to write Criteria with nest SELECT and IN clauses.

Comment: I'm sure you understood the question... :) But it _did_ ask "how to", and this post doesn't answer that question. To be really valuable, it should explain the thought process & steps taken, so that someone who didn't happen to have the exact same SQL would be able to follow the steps _supported_ by the code example.

Comment: This is true.  This example was similar to something I was doing at work and figured I'd share. A more thorough and supported response would read like a book as understand to Criteria and how to leverage it properly is a daunting task if you've never worked with it before.

Comment: Understood - but then without that backing information how valuable is the q&a - will someone new to the problem be able to proceed just with the detailed example? If it takes a book to answer, it's really not on-topic for Stack Overflow. Are there maybe just a few guiding principles that would illuminate the decisions captured in the code?